# jquery ajax request fails to catch a nonexisting ajax url

Tags: jquery, ajax

I don't know jquery. I prepared my jquery code by reading examples and [jQuery.ajax() | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

I observe jquery via console of Firefox's developer mode. (F12)

**3 findings:**

**1** Ajax works as expected & successfully if url parameter does exists correctly and  response format setting is json `dataType: "json"`.

**2** However when I intentionally feed a nonexisting url with `dataType: "json"`, ajax tries to output the html source code of PHP-assessed-page, then gives syntax error since html source code is not a proper json string.

**3** when I intentionally feed a nonexisting url without any `dataType: "json"`, ajax seems successful and response is the full source code of my PHP side's 404 page!

my `.htaccess` redirects all requests to index.php. If target url seems invalid then a 404 page is shown.

So, it seems to me that at some point `event.preventDefault()` can not prevent PHP side assessment of the flow.

error setting in my ajax never works. (`jqXHR.status` is always `200` for example)

briefly:

- domain/create-project  (form and jquery ajax request are in this page. ajax url is a
  nonexisting one.)
- after submitting the form
- ajax works & response is the html source of my 404 page while my jquery code doesn't know about my 404 page.

why this happens? how to correct this? regards, thanks

**create project form & jquery page**

```
html header part

html code for navigation

<form id="projeOlusturmaFormu">
    <input type="text" name="projeAdi" id="projeAdi">
    <button type="submit">Create Project</button>
</form>

<script src="http://127.0.0.1/nsis/v0/html/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- create project jquery -->
<script src="http://127.0.0.1/nsis/v0/html/js/jquery.ajax.proje.olustur.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**jquery.ajax.proje.olustur.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("form").submit(function(event){

        event.preventDefault();

        var form = $(this);
        var formId = "#" + form.attr('id');

        $.ajax({
            url : "http://127.0.0.1/nsis/v0/kod/ajax.php/proje.veritabani.olustur.php",
            type: "POST",
            data : $(formId).serialize(), // form data submitted
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json", // type of response data
            // callback function is called when the AJAX POST is successful
            success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                console.log(responseData);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(jqXHR);
                alert(" :) ");

            },
            // callback function is called when the AJAX POST is failed
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
                if(jqXHR.status == 404) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**proje.veritabani.olustur.php**

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/json');

    $json = array();
    $json['formDataValid'] = 0;
    $json['warnings'] = array('warning 3', 'warning 5');

    // prints {"formDataValid":0,"warnings":["warning 3","warning 5"]}
    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Comment: Are you sending the correct headers when showing the 404 Error ? If you make an ajax call to an endpoint and the status code is `200 OK` then ajax thinks everything is fine, and runs your `success` callback. Make sure you get an 404 status code.

Comment: i couldn't understand what you meant. if my ajax url is `url: "nonexisting url"` ajax still thinks that eveything is fine. Isn't ajax is independent of my `.htaccess`? Why ajax still says `200 OK` despite that target ajax url is incorrect?

Comment: You said that your server shows a 404 Error Page for all pages that are not found on your server. Are you sending the correct http status code for that page or does your server send a status code 200 when showing the error page ? Go to `www.yourpage.com/nonExisitngRecource` and check the status code in your network tab

Comment: oh I got it now. let me check if I forgot **sending 404 header** via php to a nonexisting url or not.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much. Actually now I learnt more about how ajax works. I added `header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");` to my PHP code and jquery ajax just works as expected. May you please answer this question for me to accept for the future visitors. Regards.